# Android Studio - Button click not switching to next activity

Tags: java, android

Added an OnClickListener to my button. I would like it to switch to 'Step1' activity when I click the button. When I debugged it, I clicked on the button but nothing happened. It stayed on 'MyActivity' activity. Here's my main activity:

```
package apk.olley102.roothelp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Button step1btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        step1btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.step1btn);
        step1btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent openStep = new Intent("apk.olley102.roothelp.Step1");
                startActivity(openStep);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I added the button in the activity_main.xml and associated the layout to the activity. Also added MainActivity.java and Step1.java to the AndroidManifest.xml
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  Specify the behavior that you want, and the behavior that you're actually getting.  Include the exact wording of any error messages you are receiving.

Comment: Add a `Toast` before `Intent openStep = new Intent("apk.olley102.roothelp.Step1");` only to check if it is working...

Comment: Is your activity defined in the manifest?

Comment: Try this: Intent openStep = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("apk.olley102.roothelp.Step1");
startActivity( openStep  );   and Welcome to StackoverFlow.com

Comment: Yout "onClick" for sure responds. Add a log message to check this. But your Intent is wrong, It usually should use 2 arguments, the actual activity class and the activity you want to open/transfer

Comment: Yes my activity is defined in the manifest

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have finally got my button working. I had to use '.DEFAULT' in the category of my second activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Step1" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="apk.olley102.instructroot.Step1" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also I had to specify the activity '.this' in my intent.

```
step1btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent openStep = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Step1.class);
        startActivity(openStep);
    }
});
```

I debugged my app and now the button launches Step1 on click. Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually to launch an activity you specify the current one instance and the one you want to open. In your case it would be something like this:

```
Intent openStep = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Step1.class);
startActivity(openStep);
```

If you still want to launch it using an action string, check that your activity declares the intent filter in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".Step1">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="apk.olley102.roothelp.Step1" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also note that the action string does not need to match your activity name: you could name it `apk.olley102.roothelp.GOTOSTEP1` for example and use the same string when you create the intent.

Comment: No this code did not open the Step1 activity on button click. It just showed 'Root Help has stopped'.

Comment: Which code? I posted two snippets, and the second is only needed if you still want to launch your activity with a action string (that again, I don't see the point of doing it this way...). Please add the error you got in Logcat. "Root Help was stopped" does not help to diagnose anything. If you get something like "No Activity found to handle Intent" you messed up something in the action name